# Using Grafana textbox panel variable in query where clause

Tags: grafana, grafana-variable

Is there any way to use a textbox panel variable in a where clause for a state panel query?

My Dashboard has a panel variable (type Textbox) variable for current month (`$CURRENT_MONTH`) with a value of `Feb 2021`
That variable is used to update the title of a panel using `$CURRENT_MONTH`

I need to use that variable in the panel's query to complete the where clause logic

```
SELECT
  availability
FROM "mytable"
where
  dashboard='OPS Dashboard' and period=$CURRENT_MONTH
```

and throws the error
pq: syntax error at or near "2021"

(If I replace $CURRENT_MONTH with 'Feb 2021' it works just fine)

it won't work and throws the error:

Answer (score 1):

You need to pay attention to quotes:

```
SELECT availability 
FROM "mytable" 
WHERE dashboard='OPS Dashboard' 
  AND period='$CURRENT_MONTH'
```

Your homework: use Grafana query inspector and check generated SQL with and without quotes - then you should to understand a reason of quotes here.